# How to connect ubuntu server to website

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, webmin

I'm struggling all week long but something goes wrong with connecting the work-server to the website.

We want to use moodle/Suitecrm via our website. The website is set-up correctly.

I've installed everything on server and everything works via the internal ip's.

I can use Webmin and SSH from the outside. But if I want to connect suitecrm/moodle via port 80 or 8080 it doens't works. Please help me. I'll send all the info you need out of webmin.

Lenovo Thinkserver TS150

```
- Raid
- Lamp
- Webmin
- Bind9
- Uwf enabled and so the ports 80,8080,10000 and 22
- SSH
```

Comment: So you can access the webpage from the local ip (`192.168.1.X`) and `localhost`. Have you opened port 80 on the router between your server and the internet?

Comment: Yes correct it works correctly on the localhost or internal network and yes i did open upon on both

Comment: And using the external IP of your router does not connect to the website?

Comment: No I can only use it voor port:10000 (webmin) and port 22 (ssh) otherwise I get a error. Thought i would get the index.html of /var/www/html/ when going to the external ip, but with no result.

Comment: can you show us the error?

Comment: This page is currently unavailable
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT